# Digester: The element type "user" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</user>"

Tags: java, xml, apache-commons-digester

I'm using Digester to parse a xml file and I get the following error:

```
May 3, 2011 6:41:25 PM org.apache.commons.digester.Digester fatalError
SEVERE: Parse Fatal Error at line 2336608 column 3: The element type "user" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</user>".
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The element type "user" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</user>".
```

However 2336608 is the last line of my text file. I guess I'm opening a tag  and I never close it. Do you know how can I find it and fix it, in big text files ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ grep -Hin "</\?user>" Text.xml` will print out every line with either  or . If they're not nested, then you should be able to inspect that output fand find the missing close tag (when  immediately follows .  A script do do the same:

https://gist.github.com/953837

This assumes that the open and close tags are on different lines.

Answer (score 2):

Write another script which scans each file of the line and whenever it finds an open `<user>` tag, increments a counter and prints

```
line number 1234 <user> opened (1 open total)
```

and whenever it finds a close `</user>` tag, decrements the counter prints

```
line number 4546 </user> closed (0 open total)
```

Since you have one more opening tag than closing tag, the final output of this script will tell you that 1 tag was left open. However, assuming that your XML model does not allow for nested `<user>` tags, then you can assume the problemsome declaration is wherever you see the output of `line number ... <user> opened (2 open total)`.

Comment: @matt b Isn't there any faster method, such as using regular expressions from terminal ?

Comment: `$ grep -Hin "</\?user>" Text.xml` will print out every line with either `<user>` or `</user>`.  If they're not nested, then you should be able to inspect that output fand find the missing close tag (when `<user>` immediately follows `<user>`).

Comment: @I82Much thanks. However there are too many lines.. I can't find any mistake... you know if there is a way to display lines (or multiple lines) with 2 consecutive <user> without any </user> in the middle ?

Comment: By the way I'm wondering now if I'm correctly interpreting the exception

Comment: @I82Much Thanks your code is very useful and gives the exact line. BUt still I can't find out why it doesn't work. I've a very short XML file giving me the error now: http://pastie.org/1863327

Comment: @Patrick I see nothing wrong with that short XML file you posted.  Can you show us some code as to how you're trying to load the file?  And what's the stack trace on that error?

Comment: @I82Much Nevermind, I've solved by splitting the files in subfiles with "split" command.. not very efficient but I've solved.

Comment: @Patrick I don't understand.. was the file just too large?  If so, how did the small xml file exhibit the same problem?

Comment: @I82Much I don't understand either. The script you passed me were detecting an error even if everything was ok. I've gave up with code, and I've just searched for it with a "binary manual search"

Comment: @Patrick My script assumed that the open and close tags occur on different lines.  In your example they don't, so the script will erroneously report problems.

Comment: @I82Much ok, anyway if you post your comment about grep I can vote your answer

Answer (score 1):

Use `tidy -xml -e <your-xml-file>`.  http://tidy.sourceforge.net/

Tidy is a great little tool for validating HTML, and in XML mode (`-xml` above) it will validate XML as well.

It prints out line and column numbers for parse errors.

Most of the major package managers (apt, port, etc.) will have pre-built packages for it.

Comment: `xmllint` (http://www.xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) can also be used for the same purpose.

Comment: Unfortunately tidy returns me the following error: line 2336608 column 1 - Error: unexpected </collection> in <user>. In the same way the other tools do, 2336608 is the last line of my file, I need to know where <user> have been open.

Comment: </collection> is just the parent tag, on the last line

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to start scripting for detecting xml errors.
You can use the w3 xml validator for instance
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

I just pasted a 15 mb xml in there and I managed to fix it quite easily. You can also input the xml as a url if you have the possibility to upload it somewhere. Java reported the error in some place which seemed fine, but this tool localized the actual error, and after correcting that, java didn't error anymore.

There are many types of xml errors, and are not all related to the nested structure, so it is best to just use a well known tool for this. For instance, my error was an argument error(I was missing a ") but java detected a nesting problem.